# I want to compare every single element in arrays of a ArrayList<Player> with an int[ ] array

Tags: java, object, arraylist, compare

So I have an ArrayList with an object Player that has arrays with elements in it (ArrayList) and another array.
**The question is: **I want to compare the **elements** in the arrays in the object Player in the arraylist with the other array.

this is my class Player

```
public class Player{

  private String name;
  private int bet;
  private ArrayList <int []> lottorows;
```

this is my code for comparing so far:

```
    //Method that calculates no of right rows and puts it to the player
public static void NoOfRights(ArrayList<Player> a, int[] b){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        Player player = a.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < player.getRows();j++) {

               boolean isEqual = isEquals(player.getRows(j), b, 7);
               if(isEqual == true){
                   count++;
               }
               if(count == 7){
                   player.noOf7right(count);

               }
               else if(count == 6){
                   player.noOf6right(count);
               }
               else if(count == 5){
                   player.noOf5right(count);
               }
```

isEqual is a method:

```
    private static boolean isEquals(int[] j, int[] b, int size) {

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        if(j[i] == b[i]) {
             return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

.getRows() is a method in Player:

```
public int[] getRows(int a){
      return lottorows.get(a);
   }
```

I will appreciate your help! 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want to compare the elements the class Player holds with my other array b

Answer (score 4):

This comes down to comparing arrays.
You could use:

`if(Arrays.equals(array1, array2)) count++;`

Comment: I wanna compare the elements in the arrays. so first fetch them from player and then compare them, all the arrays will only contain 7 elemets

Answer (score 0):

add this line in Player class

```
private int SumOfRIghts;
```

and this 2 methods

```
public void setSumOfRights(int sum){
    SumOfRights = sum;
}

public int NumOfRights(int [] numbers){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<lottorows.size();i++){
        for (j = 0; j<numbers.lenght){
            if(lottorows.get(i)==numbers[j]) count++;
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

and then you can do that

```
public static void sumOfRights(ArrayList<Player> a, int[] b){
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        a.get(i).setSumOfRights(a.get(i).NumOfRights(b));
    }
}
```